# Rails search form throwing back error Couldn't find Product with 'id'=search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I'm building an rails app to learn ruby on rails.(I'm very unexperienced)
I'm trying to implement a search bar to the app.

When I hit search rails throws back this error `Couldn't find Product with 'id'=search`

in this line 
 `# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end`

the server log shows this

```
Started GET "/products/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Desk" for ::1 at 2016-06-24 16:02:32 +0000
Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "query"=>"Desk", "id"=>"search"}
 Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'=search):
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:77:in `set_product'
```

I've been working on this search form for hours and checked out various tutorials and stackoverflow posts trying to figure this out. 
I'm totally lost but the solution is probably pretty simple.
Please can anyone help me.

this is my search form in _navbar.html.erb

```
    <div class="input-group">

    <%= form_tag search_products_path, method: 'get', class: 'navbar-form' do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control"%>
    </div>
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    </span>

  <% end %>
```

This is the products.rb model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base


  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates_presence_of :name, :price, :stock_quantity
  validates_numericality_of :price, :stock_quantity

  belongs_to :designer
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :page

  def self.search(query)

    where("name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%") 
  end

 end
```

This is the products_controller.rb

```
 class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :initialize_cart
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [ :new, :edit, :update, :create, :destroy ]
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
   @products = Product.all
  end

  def search

    @products = Product.search(params[:query]).order("created_at DESC")
    @categories = Category.joins(:products).where(:products => {:id => @products.map{|x| x.id }}).distinct

  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
   @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save
    format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
     respond_to do |format|
       if @product.update(product_params)
         format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
       else
         format.html { render :edit }
         format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end

   # DELETE /products/1
   # DELETE /products/1.json
   def destroy
     @product.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   end
 end

 private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
     @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
   def product_params
     params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image, :category_id, :stock_quantity, :designer_id, :query)
   end
 end
```

this is views/products/search.html.erb

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Description</th>
       <th>Designer</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Stock</th>
       <th>Image</th>

    </tr>
   </thead>

 <tbody>
   <% @products.each do |product| %>

     <tr>
        <td><%= link_to product.name, product %></td>
        <td><%= product.description %></td>
        <td><%= product.designer.designer_name %></td>

        <td><%= number_to_currency product.price %></td>
        <td><%= product.stock_quantity %></td>

        <td><%= image_tag product.image.thumb %></td>


    <% end %>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

and in routes.rb I have

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'products/search' => 'products#search', as: 'search_products'
  get 'pages/index'

  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/location'

  get 'pages/stockists'

  devise_for :users
   resources :categories
   resources :categories
   resources :designers
   resources :category_names
   resources :products


   resource :cart, only: [:show] do
    post "add", path: "add/:id", on: :member
   get :checkout
  end

  resources :orders, only: [ :index, :show, :create, :update ] do
    member do
     get :new_payment
      post :pay
    end
  end


   root 'pages#index'

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routes are read top to bottom.

Having declared `resources :products` before `/products/search` causes a match.

Move this line

```
post 'products/search' => 'products#search', as: 'search_products'
```

before this line

```
   resources :products
```

Otherwise your app will try to update your product with id:'search'... which of course does not exist

**Update**

Also, you will have to remove `:search` from your filter

This line in your controller

```
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :search]
```

Should become

```
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Because there is no :id in the route to associate a product

***New update***
You are using a `get` form, yet you declared a `post` route.

Change your route to

```
get 'products/search' => 'products#search', as: 'search_products'
```

Comment: Sorry, it´s still giving this error, good guess though.... I really thought this could be the right solution

Comment: Thank you but change the filter earlier according to j-dexx answer, that doen't seem to be the problem

Comment: Yes, excactly the same `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductsController#show`        `Couldn't find Product with 'id'=search`             ` # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end`

Comment: hahaha..... so simple and I spent basically the whole day to figure this out, thank you so much, you are a legend and a hero :)

Comment: hey, @Ruby Racer, If you are one fire today, you might want to check this problem of mine out to ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934228/category-to-belong-to-a-parent-category-in-navbar-in-a-e-commerce-rails-app

Answer (score 1):

Remove search from the `before_action :set_product`

Comment: thanks, but it still gives me this error if I remove it

Answer (score 1):

The params and code in controller can explain..

```
Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "query"=>"Desk", "id"=>"search"}
 Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'=search):
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:77:in `set_product'
```

In the parameters params[:id] is "search" and params[:query] is "Desk" which seems ok and what you did in the controller is

```
@products = Product.search(params[:query]).order("created_at DESC")
@categories = Category.joins(:products).where(:products => {:id => @products.map{|x| x.id }}).distinct
```

This code seems it is not being executing when you click search bottom it is hitting search action with get method but it agains move to show action and you have set instance variable before show action and your params[:id] which is 'search'  is querying as @product = Product.find('search'). The error is obvious.

Did you figure out your route is set as post

```
 post 'products/search' => 'products#search', as: 'search_products'
```

and you are sending get request..

Comment: thanks @Shadow, Yeah that seamed to be the problem, sometimes the problem is so obvious that one can't see it :)

Comment: Welcome @DaðiHall  :). We are here to help each other